# Printing out packing result from struct.pack

Tags: python, pack, struct.pack

struct.pack returns packed result from input value.

```
In [19]: pack("i",4)
Out[19]: '\x04\x00\x00\x00'
```

I'm trying to printout the packed result as follows:

```
val = pack("i", 4)
print "%d" % int(val[0])
```

However, I got ValueError:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x04'
```

How can I print the packed value?

Comment: Would printing it out via `unpack` not provide what you want?  What is your desired output?  `4`?

Comment: If you want to reproduce what Python prints in your first example, use `print repr(val)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was for hexadecimal value conversion, I had to use ord() method. int() method is only for a number in a string with base 10.

```
In [33]: int('4')
Out[33]: 4

In [34]: ord('\x34')
Out[34]: 52

In [35]: ord('4')
Out[35]: 52

In [36]: ord('\x10')
Out[36]: 16
```

So, this code works.

```
val = pack("i", 4)
print "%d" % ord(val[0]) # -> 4
```

or

```
print "%s" % hex(ord(val[0])) # -> 0x4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import struct
>>> print struct.unpack("i", struct.pack("i",4))[0]
4
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on: http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html

Python packs structures as byte strings, printing:
`print "%d" % int(val[0])`
Will print the first character of the byte string (which is a character not an integer).

You are porobably look struct.unpack(fmt, string) from http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html.

```
i = pack("i",'\x04\x00\x00\x00')
print i
```